# DSC-HX400 RAW image data & Movie Recording

Tags: camera, sony

I am currently testing a DSC-HX400.  While I am able to do almost everything I need to with the camera there are a couple of items that are not exposed via the API that have frustrated my efforts.

1) The camera does not seem to offer an option, via the API or the camera itself, to capture images in RAW format.  It does offer standard & fine JPEG format but both of those are leaving artifacts in the image that become extremely noticeable when you zoom in with an image editor.  Is there a way to get the camera to capture RAW images?  I do not need the SDK to return the data just to save it out to the card.  If getting the RAW data is impossible has anyone found an inventive way to clean up the artifacts?

2) The camera supports both still shoot and movie mode but the API will only expose the mode that I am currently in.  It makes it impossible to transition between still to movie mode (to allow recording) from the API but I can do that same transition by pressing a single button on the camera.  Once I am recording a movie the API will allow me to transition back to still mode (by cancelling recording).  Is there plans to support the ability to trigger a movie recording via the API if you are in a still capture mode (Seeing the firmware already supports this functionality)?

Answer (score 0):

Answers to the questions below:

1. If the camera cannot capture RAW images, the API will not be able to either.  I do not know of a way to capture RAW images but can only comment with regards to the API as I am not an expert on usage of the camera itself.
2. You can change between still and movie mode by using the "setShootMode" API.

Comment: Thanks for answering the questions.  In regards to the image quality hopefully future cameras you develop will support uncompressed image formats so we can take advantage the 20MP image without having to deal with artifacts.

In regards to the second item the issue is not finding the API only that when I call for the 'getAvailableShootMode' the system will only return still or movie based on which scene selection I am in. At no point will the camera expose the other mode as available so transitioning is impossible.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.  Will getAvailableShootMode return both still and movie if you are using either Intelligent or Superior Auto mode?

Comment: In both of those modes I only receive 'still' as an option.  The only time I received 'movie' as an option was when I was in the movie scene selection at which point still was no longer returned.